# Java Date localization

Tags: java

How can I set the localization so that java.util.Date have the German format? ( ie: dd.mm.yyyy ) . I need to send to a Webservice a Date(), but it can be only on this format. Not as String but as a Date Object.

Thank you

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A java.util.Date doesn't have a format. The format only comes into play when you parse a String as a Date or format a Date for display. Internally the date is just a long.

To format an instance of a Date object as a String you can use the SimpleDateFormat class in java.text

```
formatter = new SimpleDateFormatter("dd.mm.yyyy");
String formattedDate = formatter.format(new Date());
```

Answer (score 1):

[SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html)  is a concrete class for formatting and parsing dates in a locale-sensitive manner.

Something like this would serve your case,

```
Date today;
String output;
SimpleDateFormat formatter;

formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");
today = new Date();
output = formatter.format(today);
System.out.println(output);
```

See this for more help : [Customizing Formats](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/i18n/format/simpleDateFormat.html)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by [Eric](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95186/eric-rosenberg), `java.util.Date` does not have a format. If your Web Service returning a Date as a Date object, then the WS client should convert it to its desired format. In your case it is `dd.mm.yyyy`. Simple and best utility is `SimpleDateFormat` that formats a `Date` to the desired pattern and returns a `String`. You can't deny a String here because you need a formatted date object.

Answer (score 0):

The modern solution uses *java.time*.

### Avoid legacy date-time classes

You are using terribly flawed classes that were years ago supplanted by the modern *java.time* classes defined in JSR 310. You will find *java.time* built into Java 8+.

### `LocalDate`

To represent a date-only value, without a time-of-day, and without a time zone or offset, use the `java.time.LocalDate` class.

```
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.of( 2024 , Month.JANUARY , 23 ) ;
```

> the German format

To generate text in a localized format, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalized…`. Specify a `Locale` to determine the localization rules to be using in translation and cultural norms.

```
Locale locale = Locale.GERMANY ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate( FormatStyle.SHORT ).withLocale( locale ) ;
String output = ld.format( f ) ;
```

If that localization is not to you taste, define a custom formatting pattern with `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern`.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu" ) ;
```

> need to send to a Webservice a Date(), but it can be only on this format.

The ideal solution would be to educate the developers of that Web service about using only standard [ISO 8601](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) formats for exchanging date-time values rather than localized formats.

In the meantime, use `DateTimeFormatter.ofLocalizedDate` or `DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern` as discussed above.